how to re numbering after filter data vba excel
I want to ask after i run macro for filtering the number not start from 1 how to renumbering or auto numbering the data after filtering?
here the code i use
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C13:N3200").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("D3:G4"), CopyToRange:=Range("D13:M13"), Unique:= _
        False
    Range("D14:M427").Select

     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("L13:L482"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = top-to-bottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

how to make number start again from 1 after filtering
the table before filter

the table after filtering


Is this access or excel? Please use only tags relevant for the question. And what do you mean with renumbering? You want to get "Intiguna" to start at 1? What should happen when you remove the filter (or set a new one? What should happen if you sort the data?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

On a side note, qualify each range with its worksheet (e.g. Sheets("Sheet2").Range(...)) or there will be mayhem if the wrong sheet (e.g. not Sheet2) is active when running the code. Similarly, qualify each sheet with its workbook. Use variables to avoid unnecessary typing. Q1.) Is this code in the workbook containing these sheets? Q2.) Where are the numbers to be replaced located? In column Sheet2!L:L?
